# PageRouting doesn't seem to work in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that uses TABs (BottomNavigationBar) to move between pages.
How does this affect page routing?
I am having a serious problem in getting a page to pop up.

I'm calling a page (built as a stateful widget) through its constructor. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

when it doesn't work, I get an index error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

Here's how I'm calling my stateful class:

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page4(
                                                      param1: listParams[ctr]['param1'],
                                                      param2: listParams[ctr]['param2'],
                                                    )));
```

Here is my code for the Main Widget:

Here are my page routes:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    title: 'MyApp',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    ),
    home: BottomNavigationBarController(),
    //initialRoute: '/',
    routes:
    {
      //'/': (context) => Page1Class(),
      Page1Class.id: (context) => Page1Class(),
      Page2Class.id: (context) => Page2Class(),
      Page3Class.id: (context) => Page3Class(),
      Page4Class.id: (context) => Page4Class(),
      Page5Class.id: (context) => Page5Class(),
      Page6Class.id: (context) => Page6Class()
        }
    );
  }
}
```

The BottomNavigationBarController() class is here:

```
class BottomNavigationBarController extends StatefulWidget
{


  @override
  _BottomNavigationBarControllerState createState() =>      _BottomNavigationBarControllerState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarControllerState extends       State<BottomNavigationBarController> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{


final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
int _selectedIndex = 0;


  final List<Widget> pages =
  [

  Page1Class(
  key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),),

Page2Class(
  key: PageStorageKey('Page2'),),

Page3Class(
  key: PageStorageKey('Page3'),),

  ];

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
return Scaffold(
  drawer: mydrawer(),
  bottomNavigationBar:

       FancyBottomNavigation(
    barBackgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    activeIconColor: Colors.amberAccent,
    initialSelection: _selectedIndex,
    //textColor: Colors.black,
    tabs: [

      TabData(iconData: Icons.heart, title: "Page1"),
      TabData(iconData: Icons.graph, title: "Page2"),
      TabData(iconData: Icons.search, title: "Page3"),

    ],
    onTabChangedListener: (position) {
      setState(() {
        print('Selected Index = ' + _selectedIndex.toString());
        _selectedIndex = position;
      });
    },
  ),

  body: PageStorage(
  child: pages[_selectedIndex],
  bucket: bucket,
),
);
 }
}
```

I have tried everything. Im really becoming desperate now.

As you can see, I have 3 tabs and each tab is a page. However, I have Page4 (a 4th page) that is a Stateful widget that pops up whenever I need to call it from either page 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got same error

Comment: yes... I found. So that error gives you a false impression. It is not a good error. Why? Because it makes you think there's a problem with routing. There isn't. The problem is with an array. It was incorrect. Go and check your code

Comment: Oh! I thought it was something about routes, I'm gonna take a look my code, thanks!!